# PrimeNg Autocomplete with virtualScroll - auto width

Tags: autocomplete, primeng

I have a problem with PrimeNG Autocomplete component. When I add Virtual Scroll to it: [virtualScroll]="true" , then drop-down list adjust width to input width. Without VirtualScroll, the list width is aligned to the longest item in the list. Is it possible to have it with VirtualScroll option on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Did you had any luck ?